# В функцию передаю параметр i по ссылке, но вот такой цикл не работает. Как по нормальному сделать что бы использовать i в цикле?

Tags: c#

```
 private void takepart(string ex,ref int i)
        {
            string res="(";
            for(i;i<ex.Length;i++)
            {
                if(ex[i] >= 65 && ex[i] <= 95 || )
                res += ex[i];
            }
            res += ")";
            return res;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка здесь:

> for(i ;i < ex.Length;i++)

У вас неправильно задан цикл. В качестве оператора могут использоваться только выражения присваивания, вызова, инкремента, декремента и создания нового объекта.
Пример:

```
for( i = 0;i<ex.Length;i++)
```

Можете создать другую перменную и присвоить ей значение i:

```
for( int j = i;j<ex.Length;j++)
```